# Angular-google-maps not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

The past week I've been implementing Google's JavaScript Maps API for a simple project. So far I've been using the Autocomplete service and PlacesService with no problem. When adding the interactive map, I was having trouble with the map not loading all the time due to the asynchronous nature of it. I've since transferred to using the angular-google-maps plugin. I am not using the SDK loader as I feel it is redundant to load the library twice since I already have loaded it for the Autocomplete and PlacesService. I have followed the very basic example but the map just will not show up. Common errors I have checked:

- Gave html, body, and map div a height.
- Made sure library was being loaded before any use of the angular module and double-checked API key
- The same thing happens when using the SDK loader so I am pretty sure that is not causing it. The Autocomplete and PlacesService work so the library is working in that case.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="map" class="well">
                <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center"
                                    zoom="map.zoom"
                                    pan="true"
                >
                </ui-gmap-google-map>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("IndexCtrl", ["$scope", "$interval", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", function($scope, $interval, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    var Autocomplete;
    var PlacesService;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("placeInput"), {});
        PlacesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("map"));
    });

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }, zoom: 2 };
        $scope.googleVersion = maps.version;
        maps.visualRefresh = true;

    });

}]);
```

CSS:

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 400px;
}

.angular-google-map {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome. By posting this and posting just the culprit code, I noticed I am using the same div as the angular-google-maps module as a container for my PlacesService. By changing this, the map rendered fine.

New Controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("IndexCtrl", ["$scope", "$interval", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", function($scope, $interval, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    var Autocomplete;
    var PlacesService;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("placeInput"), {});
        PlacesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placesContainer"));
    });

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }, zoom: 2 };
        $scope.googleVersion = maps.version;
        maps.visualRefresh = true;

    });

}]);
```

New HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div class="well">
                <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center"
                                    zoom="map.zoom"
                                    pan="true"
                >
                </ui-gmap-google-map>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```